# shp2pgsql srid 2262 polygons NOT in geocordinates

Tags: postgis

Imported the following shape file:

```
shp2pgsql -c -s 2262 MCGIS_Towns_Villages public.towns | pgsql -d database
```

Queried:

```
SELECT gid, name,st_astext(the_geom) as the_geom FROM towns
```

The multipolygon I get back is does NOT have points that are in latitude longitude types of numbers.

If I do:

```
 SELECT gid, name,st_askml(the_geom) as the_geom FROM towns
```

The data I get back has latitude and longitude type of data.

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The KML Standard uses degrees Latitude/Longitude for coordinates. You cannot use any other coordinate type, such as Easting/Northing in feet.

The PostGIS function [ST_AsKML(geom)](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/browser/trunk/postgis/postgis.sql.in.c#L3449) has an embedded ST_Transform(geom, 4326) call within it, so that your output conforms to the KML Standard, with Lat/Lon coordinates.

If you want to use an XML format that keeps your original coordinates, consider GML.

Answer (score 0):

That seems reasonable as [EPSG:2262](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2262/) is measured in feet. Either use ST_Transform to reproject your coordinates on output in the data base or use [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) to reproject the shapefile to [EPSG:4326](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/) to get a lat/lon based dataset before you use shp2pgsql for the import.